# Conditional rendering like php in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to achieve this php code in react:

```
    <?php
    for ($i = 0; $i < arr.length; $i++) {

    if ($i % 2 == 0) {
    ?>
        <div className="columns">
    <?php
    }
    ?>

    <div className="column is-half">
     <Card />
    </div>

    <?php
    if ($i % 2 == 0) {
    ?>
        </div>
    <?php
    }
}
    ?>
```

I have tried to make something like this:

```
renderOpenDiv (i) {
    return (<div className="columns">);
    }

renderCloseDiv (i) {
    return (</div>);
    }
```

So make different function and make conditional rendering, but I am forced to close the tag immediately, how I can achieve this?

Comment: Is it a set of tags and you want to display tag only if some particular condition is satisfied?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
renderDiv(i) {
  if (/*condition for div being open*/) {
    return (<div className="columns">);
  } else if (/*condition for div being closed*/) {
    return (</div>);
  }
}
```

Comment: have you tried it? Because it's not working, like i said in my question:  "but I am forced to close the tag immediately"

Comment: @piero Can't try it without the rest of the code that is intented to work with but that would work as far as what you want.comparisons

Comment: you can't make that function in react, give me an error, have you tried it?